# Как узнать точное название браузера в php?

Tags: браузер

Нужно узнать **точное  название браузера без версии средствами php**, спасибо.
Чтобы выводило, например: MSIE или Opera или Chrome и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Задача не имеет решения при использовании только php.

Answer (score 4):

Через суперглобальный массив.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Через `get_browser`.

Или, как заметили ниже, через сторонние решения - [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php).

Comment: Помимо собственно названия браузера, user-agent содержит еще и кучу всякого мусора. Вычленить от туда реальное название -- отдельная сложная задача.

Comment: Просто распарсить как строку. Проверить на наличие определенных подстрок.

Comment: Это вам только так кажется. На самом деле, правила разбора ой-какие нетривиальные. Например, почти каждый user-agent содержит строку `Mozilla` (даже те, что не имеют вообще никакого отношения к этой компании). Еще часто встречается строка MSIE, но это вовсе не значит, что браузер = IE. [Любопытный пример](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browzar/).

Comment: Тогда через `get_browser`. Этот вариант удобней, но я не сказал бы что он легче.

Comment: На самом деле нужно просто использовать специальный инструмент для разбора user-agent =)) Например, [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php).

Comment: Ну или через сторонние решения, конечно)

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить это в ответ, иначе он не полный =)

Comment: Добавил. Спасибо за замечания)

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']    - бесполезна, в строке эксплорера вообще нету MSIE, к примеру